# How to stop XMLHttpRequest refresh page

Tags: reactjs, xmlhttprequest

I am working on a react app and implemented a method to download a file on click on a button, I call following function on click to download file. It works fine but it also refreshes the page. How can I stop page refresh after file download ?

```
printClientsData(popupResponse) {
        this._confirmPopup.closePopup();
        if (popupResponse) {
            this.setState({
                loading: true,
                showLoadingMsg: true,
                loadingText: 'Generating PDF...',
            })
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open("POST", "http://example.com", true);
            req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            req.setRequestHeader("x-auth-token", localStorage.getItem('token'));

            req.responseType = "blob";

            req.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
                if (req.readyState === 4 && req.status === 200) {
                    let filename = "PdfName-" + new Date().getTime() + ".pdf";
                    let myHeader = req.getResponseHeader('file-name');
                    if (myHeader !== null) {
                        filename = myHeader;
                    }
                    if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob === 'function') {
                        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(req.response, filename);
                        this.setState({
                            loading: false,
                            showLoadingMsg: false
                        })
                        NotificationManager.success('QR Code Generated Successfully');
                    } else {
                        var blob = req.response;
                        var link = document.createElement('a');
                        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        link.download = filename;

                        document.body.appendChild(link);
                        link.click();
                        this.setState({
                            loading: false,
                            showLoadingMsg: false
                        })
                        NotificationManager.success('QR Code Generated Successfully');
                        return false
                    }
                    e.preventDefault()
                }

            };
            req.send(JSON.stringify(this.selectedClients));

        }

    }
```

Comment: Use this `e.preventDefault()` on top of the function.

When calling that function, pass the event and use `e.preventDefault()` at the top.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me too. Im so stupid that in my render method my button is inside the form element so every time I clicked the button it refresh the page. So make sure to add type="button" property in the button  or  add preventdefault in  "onSubmit" property of the form

Comment: it would work if my button is under a form , but here I have a standalone button without form. I am also opening a confirm box before file download so not sure how to stop it now